# Exponentiating Lie algebra element does not result in algebraic group element

Tags: lie-algebras, quadratic-forms, algebraic-groups, bilinear-form, root-systems

This question is about a particular case of the special orthogonal groups considered in section 23.4 of Borel's *Linear Algebraic Groups*. Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $\neq 2$. Let $F$ be a nondegenerate isotropic symmetric bilinear form on $k^6$ of Witt index 2, so we can write the matrix of $F$ as
$$
F = \begin{pmatrix}
&& I_2 \\
& F_o \\
I_2
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
F_o =\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 \\
& a_2
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
a_1, a_2 \in k^\times
$$
where $I_2$ is the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix, and $F_o$ is the anisotropic component of $F$. Let $G = \operatorname{SO}(F)$ be the associated special orthogonal group.
$$
G = \{ X \in \operatorname{SL}_6(k) : X^t F X = F \}
$$
$X^t$ denotes the matrix transpose. The Lie algebra of $G$ is
$$
\mathfrak{g} = \{ A \in \mathfrak{gl}_6(k) : A F + FA^t = 0 \}
$$
Let $S$ be the following maximal $k$-split torus in $G$ (note the rank of $S$ equals the Witt index of $F$, this is true in general).
$$
S = \left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
s_1 \\
& s_2 \\
&& 1 \\
&&& 1 \\
&&&& s_1^{-1} \\
&&&&& s_2^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}
: s_1, s_2 \in k^\times
\right\}
$$
Let $y_i:S \to k^\times$ be the character which picks off the $i$th diagonal entry. The root space corresponding to the character $y_1$ is
$$
 \mathfrak{g}_{y_1} = \left\{ A(x_1, x_2) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & & x_1 & x_2 \\
  & 0 \\
  && 0 && - a_1 x_1 \\
  &&& 0 & -a_2 x_2 \\
  &&&& 0 \\
  &&&&& 0
 \end{pmatrix}
: x_1, x_2 \in k
\right\}
$$
As I understand it, it should be the case that the corresponding root subgroup of $G$ is the image of $\mathfrak{g}_{y_1}$ under the matrix exponential map. However, if $A \in \mathfrak{g}_{y_1}$, my calculations show that $\exp(A)$ need not lie in $G$ at all. In particular, taking $A = A(x_1, x_2)$,
$$
\exp(A) = 1 + A + \frac 12 A^2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & & x_1 & x_2 & - \frac 12 (a_1 x_1^2 + a_2 x_2^2) \\
  & 1 \\
  && 1 && - a_1 x_1 \\
  &&& 1 & -a_2 x_2 \\
  &&&& 1 \\
  &&&&& 1
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
The matrix $X = \exp(A)$ does not satisfy $X^t F X = F$. Concretely, the defect is
$$
X^t F F - X = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0  \\
& 0 \\
&& 0 && -x_1(a_1^2-1) \\
&&& 0 \\
&& -x_1(a_1^2-1) && a_1 x_1^2( a_1^2 - 1) \\
&&&&& 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Thus $X \in G$ if and only if $a_1^2 = 1$. But to the best of my knowledge, over a general field $k$ we cannot assume that the anisotropic nondegenerate form $F_o$ can be diagonalized with diagonal entries $\pm 1$. This is certainly possible if $k = \mathbb{R}$ (or slightly more generally), but in section 23.4 Borel makes no assumption about $k$ other than that the characteristic is not 2, so I don't think I should need additional assumptions either.

My question is: **Why is it not the case that $\exp(A) \in G$?** Have I just made a calculation error somewhere, or maybe I have misunderstood something about the relationship between an algebraic group and its Lie algebra.

Answer (score 2):

This entire confusion is just due to some very minor transpose issues. I had missed the fact that Borel takes opposite conventions in where to put the matrix transpose in section 23.4 versus in 23.9. If $G = \operatorname{SO}(F)$ is defined as in the question, then the Lie algebra condition should be $A^t F + FA = 0$, not the slightly different $A F + FA^t = 0$. This small change means that the matrix $A = \exp(X)$ in the question does not actually belong to the Lie algebra.

An alternative fix is to keep the same Lie algebra condition, and replace $X^t FX = F$ in the definition of $G$ with the slightly different $XFX^t = F$. Then it does work out that $X = \exp(A)$ lies in $G$.